# Does MongoDB sort() break JSON spec?

Tags: json, mongodb

To pass in multiple fields to sort on in MongoDB you pass in a JSON object:

```
db.col.find({category: A}).sort({updated: -1, rating: -1})
```

However, according to http://json.org:

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.

Which means that, depending on implementation, the order of fields ("updated" and "rating") can be interpreted in any order.

As far as I can tell, MongoDB always reads them in order, but this is not really guaranteed by JSON spec. Am I missing something? Is MongoDB using some extended JSON spec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB does not use JSON.

MongoDB uses [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/) for both internal storage and as a communication interface. A binary variant of JSON which *does* have strict ordering of fields.

The MongoDB shell is a Javascript interpreter which transparently converts between BSON and JSON. When you enter the query above into the MongoDB shell, the shell converts it to BSON and then sends that BSON document to MongoDB. The results also arrive in BSON and then get converted to a Javascript representation before they are outputted on the user interface.